# How to add external .java files as library in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, ide

I've been looking everywhere, and every post on SO, or tutorial explains how to import a library to a project using .jar files, but the files I have are .java, and nothing I've tried worked so far. Our teacher wants us to implement a JSON file reader in our assignment, using [this](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library, and importing it using `import org.json.*;` but no matter how I tried (using project settings -> modules -> dependencies or proj. settings -> libraries), IntelliJ gives me an error when I try importing it. What am I missing?

Comment: You seem to be confusing *importing* classes into your Java file scope using `import` and *adding them to the classpath*. Importing is just a shortcut so you don't have to type `org.json.Whatever` all over the place and is orthogonal to where those classes are provided.

Comment: Quite possibly. How would I go about _importing_ the classes I need to my project?

Comment: Nevermind, I wasn't using the right files haha